# optimize speed display GEOJSON on google api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geojson

I'am displaying  geojson with the function below. In my geojson file, I've approximately 12 000 records and the display lag.. is slow. Do you know a way to optimize speed ?
Data displying are polylines.

```
 countyLayer = new google.maps.Data();
 countyLayer.loadGeoJson('orange.json');

 countyLayer.setMap(map);

 countyLayer.setStyle(function(feature) {
    return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */({
    strokeColor: "#2D241E",
    strokeWeight: feature.getProperty('stroke')/7
    });
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: OP said he is displaying polylines, not markers.

Comment: I can't think of a way to optimize the display of polylines. Maybe you should review your use case. Could you eventually display less polylines at lower zoom levels, or display them only at higher zoom levels (which would mean displaying less polylines)?

Comment: Do you know that is possible to display just certain object of geojson ?

Comment: Please define *certain object of geojson*. And is that a question or an affirmation? If it's a question, then what does your geojson look like?

Comment: it look like this : {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
{"type": "Feature","properties": {"stroke": "2"},"geometry": {"type": "MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-0.05, 45.00], [-0.05, 45.00]]]}},
{"type": "Feature","properties": {"stroke": "2"},"geometry": {"type": "MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-0.05, 45.00], [-0.05, 45.00]]]}},
{"type": "Feature","properties": {"stroke": "3"},"geometry": {"type": "MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-0.05, 45.00], [-0.05, 45.00]]]}}}] I need to display the element when stroke = 2

Comment: Don't you have a way to construct your geojson with only what you need? Of course you can remove a feature from the map, but in any case, you have to load the geojson first. So this is not a way to optimize speed.

Comment: I think your are wright. To optimize speed I need to build geojson only with element that I need. Is it possible to build dynamically an heavy geojson with php ?

Comment: Of course you can. There are libraries that can help you with that. Otherwise see PHP `json_encode`.